# Nested list <li> expanding and repositioning outside parent in IE9+

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-position, internet-explorer-11

I'm having an issue where a drop down menu's children are expanding and repositioning to come outside of the parent's bounds. The concerned element is the menu item "BEHANDLINGAR"'s drop down list in IE9+.

Be warned that I am very much a junior developer; this might be apparent from my code. I don't want to discourage general advice, as I do need it, but please focus on the problem at hand first and foremost.

The site is: [www.skinwellnessofsweden.com/hudvard.html](http://skinwellnessofsweden.com/hudvard.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of the `ul` style. The style applied the all the `ul` elements in general. You have to apply it for only the specific child list like the following.

```
ul.clearfix {
    padding-left: calc(50% - 480px);
}
```

Hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! It is a lot better now.